# Weierstrass M-test with absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

The Weierstrass M-test states

> Suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of complex-valued functions defined on a set $A$ and that there is a sequence of non-negative numbers $(M_n)$ such that $|f_n(z)|\le M_n$ for all $n\ge 1$ and all $z\in A$ and such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n$ converges. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $A$.

Question: Suppose that we add the hypothesis that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$ converges absolutely on $A$. Taking $M_n=f_n(z)$, it seems that the Weierstrass M-test implies that each absolutely convergent series is uniformly convergent. Where is the error in this reasoning?

Comment: you misunderstand the older question you refer too; there specifically the hypothesis is that $|f_n(x)| \le g_n(x)$ and $\sum g_n(x)$ converges uniformly implying $\sum f_n(x)$ converging absolutely and uniformly; so applying this to $f_n$ you get the trivial fact that if $\sum |f_n(x)|$ converges uniformly then $\sum f_n$ does too